# A change in namespace prefix now returns null in WCF response

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I generated years ago a wcf proxy from a wsdl in C# using VS2015.
I've been notified from the provider that the response contract has changed. They removed the prefix of the namespace as seen here (note two places):

Before:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:Encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <toto:ExportDataResponse xmlns:toto="company">
        <Data>blahblahblah</Data>
    </toto:ExportDataResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

After:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:Encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <ExportDataResponse xmlns="company">
          <Data>blahblahblah</Data>
      </ExportDataResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I performed a search looking for the prefix but I am unsure where it is specified. Is it in the wsdl file or in the generated Reference.cs file?

I then proceeded to update my service reference using the new server's wsdl.
I noticed the generated code hasn't changed when I compare the Reference.cs with its previous version (could it be that the "new" wsdl that I am using hasn't been updated to reflect the changes? Is that possible?).

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="ExportDataResponse", WrapperNamespace="company", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class CompanyWS_Out {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public string Data;
    
    public CompanyWS_Out() {
    }
    
    public CompanyWS_Out(string Data) {
        this.Data = Data;
    }
}
```

Although the files haven't changed, I can see that if I am using the old server (with the old version of the service), the Data field actually values whereas if I am using the new server (with the new version of the service without the prefix), Data is null.

I am uncertain how to proceed or where to even begin troubleshooting this issue.
I thought it would be as simple as just updating the service reference or looking for the prefix in the generated code and removing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have IDispatchMessageInspector class in your code, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609423/17218587).

Comment: @LanHuang This lead me to the right solution. Thank you. Although I used IClientMessageInspector instead because I need to change the incoming response from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing IClientMessageInspector and changed the incoming response from the client side.

Heavily inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609423/17218587), thank you @LanHuang.

```
public class CorrectorInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message request, object correlationState)
        {
            request = FilterMessage(request);
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message reply, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            return null;
        }

        private Message FilterMessage(Message originalMessage)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream);
            originalMessage.WriteMessage(xmlWriter);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
            string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            xmlWriter.Close();

            body = body.Replace("ExportDataResponse", "toto:ExportDataResponse");
            body = body.Replace("xmlns=\"company\"", "xmlns:toto=\"company\"");

            memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
            XmlDictionaryReader xmlDictionaryReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
            Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(xmlDictionaryReader, int.MaxValue, originalMessage.Version);

            //memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
            //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream);
            //Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, originalMessage.Version);

            newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(originalMessage.Properties);
            return newMessage;
        }
    }
```